# Which one is the right version of openssl for nginx?

Tags: php, linux, ssl, nginx, openssl

```
4441 2016-Jan-28 14:38:54 openssl-1.0.1r.tar.gz (SHA256) (PGP sign) (SHA1)
5135 2016-Jan-28 14:38:54 openssl-1.0.2f.tar.gz (SHA256) (PGP sign) (SHA1)
4906 2016-Feb-15 18:56:05 openssl-1.1.0-pre3.tar.gz (SHA256) (PGP sign) (SHA1)
1420 2016-Feb-13 20:13:39 openssl-fips-2.0.12.tar.gz (SHA256) (PGP sign) (SHA1)
1399 2016-Feb-13 20:13:39 openssl-fips-ecp-2.0.12.tar.gz (SHA256) (PGP sign) (SHA1)
```

I use nginx-1.9.11
openssl-1.1.0-pre3 openssl-fips-2.0.12 and openssl-fips-ecp-2.0.12 is wrong !

I use openssl-1.0.2f now,It's ok.

which one can used for nginx?

What is the difference between fips and ecp ?